# SELECT query with multiple sub-queries for counts

Tags: sql-server, select, count, sql-server-2012

I just wrote this query for a report.  But I originally wrote it without the date range filter on every sub-query.  But that didn't work.  So I added it to each sub-query.  And that worked, but I don't really like having to repeat it every time, is there syntax to do the same thing simpler?

```
 SELECT Count(r.id)                       AS cnt_total,
   (SELECT Count(r1.entity_id)
    FROM   auto_reminders_members r1
    WHERE  r1.reminder_id = r.reminder_id
           AND r1.date_last_reminder BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '03/28/2013',
                                             101)
                                             AND
               CONVERT(DATETIME,
               '03/28/2013' + ' 23:59:59.997 ', 101)
           AND r1.action = 'notnow') AS cnt_notnow,
   (SELECT Count(r1.entity_id)
    FROM   auto_reminders_members r1
    WHERE  r1.reminder_id = r.reminder_id
           AND r1.date_last_reminder BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '03/28/2013',
                                             101)
                                             AND
               CONVERT(DATETIME,
               '03/28/2013' + ' 23:59:59.997 ', 101)
           AND r1.action = 'insert') AS cnt_insert,
   (SELECT Count(r1.entity_id)
    FROM   auto_reminders_members r1
    WHERE  r1.reminder_id = r.reminder_id
           AND r1.date_last_reminder BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '03/28/2013',
                                             101)
                                             AND
               CONVERT(DATETIME,
               '03/28/2013' + ' 23:59:59.997 ', 101)
           AND r1.action = 'update') AS cnt_update,
   (SELECT Count(r1.entity_id)
    FROM   auto_reminders_members r1
    WHERE  r1.reminder_id = r.reminder_id
           AND r1.date_last_reminder BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '03/28/2013',
                                             101)
                                             AND
               CONVERT(DATETIME,
               '03/28/2013' + ' 23:59:59.997 ', 101)
           AND r1.action = 'verify') AS cnt_verify
FROM   auto_reminders_members r
WHERE  r.reminder_id = 1
       AND r.date_last_reminder BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '03/28/2013', 101) AND
                                            CONVERT(DATETIME,
                                            '03/28/2013' + ' 23:59:59.997 ', 101
                                            )
GROUP  BY r.reminder_id
```

Comment: is sub query part always will be same ?

Comment: What version of SQL Server please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a way to do that without all the sub-queries

```
SELECT  Count(r.id) AS cnt_total,
        sum(case when r.action = 'notnow' then 1 else 0 end) as 'cnt_notnow',
        sum(case when r.action = 'insert' then 1 else 0 end) as 'cnt_insert',
        sum(case when r.action = 'update' then 1 else 0 end) as 'cnt_update',
        sum(case when r.action = 'verify' then 1 else 0 end) as 'cnt_verify'        
FROM    auto_reminders_members r

WHERE  r.reminder_id = 1
       AND CONVERT(DATE, r.date_last_reminder) = '20130328'
```

I also cleaned up the query a bit, removing the group by as this will always be 1, and changing the date comparison to avoid using the messy between logic (Thanks Aaron for the comment)

Comment: FYI the [`BETWEEN` remains terrible](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx), also there is no reason to return the `reminder_id` column, never mind `GROUP BY` it, if it's a constant (`1`).

Comment: Right, I didn't pay too much attention to cleaning up that part of the query yet

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using `GROUPING SETS` and `PIVOT`, but this will hinge on the version you are using, which you forgot to tell us:

```
DECLARE @reminder_id INT, @date DATE;

SELECT @reminder_id = 1, @date = '20130328';

;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT [action] = COALESCE([action],'Total'), c2 = COUNT(*)
    FROM dbo.auto_reminders_members
    WHERE reminder_id = @reminder_id
    AND CONVERT(DATE, date_last_reminder) = @date
    GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(([action]), ())
)
SELECT reminder_id = @reminder_id, * FROM x 
PIVOT 
(
  MAX([c2]) FOR [action] IN ([Total],[notnow],[insert],[update],[verify])
) AS p;
```

If 2005, you can replace the `GROUPING SETS` line with the old-style syntax:

```
    GROUP BY [action] WITH ROLLUP
```

I really wish people would stop condoning `BETWEEN` and this magic "end of day" stuff. If you want a full day your WHERE clause should either be:

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, r.date_last_reminder) = '20130328'
```

Or, if you are on 2005:

```
WHERE r.date_last_reminder >= '20130328'
  AND r.date_last_reminder <  '20130329'
```

Some important points here, mostly that `23:59:59.997` may round up or miss data depending on the underlying data type, that there is no reason you should ever be converting a datetime value to a string to perform a query, and that regional formats like `m/d/y` are bad for a variety of reasons (for example if your query was for `03/08/2013` I wouldn't know if you were after March 8th or August 3rd).

Please read these articles:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

You should also be careful about using reserved words / keywords for column names, like `entity_id` and `action`.

Comment: This is very interesting, I went with the first approach by doing sums, and that worked for this project, but I have a much more complex query I have to do a bunch of different counts on for a different project, where this might be more appropriate.  Never seen anything like it.  BTW, we are on SQL SErver 2012

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do something like this

```
SELECT Count(r.id) AS cnt_total,
  SUM(CASE WHEN r1.action = 'notnow') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt_notnow,
  SUM(CASE WHEN r1.action = 'insert') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt_insert,
  SUM(CASE WHEN r1.action = 'update') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt_update,
  SUM(CASE WHEN r1.action = 'verify') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt_verify,

FROM   auto_reminders_members r
WHERE  r.reminder_id = 1
       AND r.date_last_reminder BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '03/28/2013', 101) AND
                                            CONVERT(DATETIME,
                                            '03/28/2013' + ' 23:59:59.997 ', 101
                                            )
GROUP  BY r.reminder_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
    reminder_id,
    count(1) as Total,
    sum(case when  r1.action = 'notnow' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_notnow,
    sum(case when  r1.action = 'insert' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_insert,
    sum(case when  r1.action = 'update' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_update,
    sum(case when  r1.action = 'verify' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_verify
from auto_reminders_members r
WHERE  r.reminder_id = 1
   AND r.date_last_reminder BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '03/28/2013', 101) AND
                                        CONVERT(DATETIME,
                                        '03/28/2013' + ' 23:59:59.997 ', 101
                                        )
GROUP  BY r.reminder_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Found one alternate solution:

```
 SELECT Sum(1)   AS cnt_total,
   Sum(CASE
         WHEN r.action = 'notnow' THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END) AS cnt_notnow,
   Sum(CASE
         WHEN r.action = 'insert' THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END) AS cnt_insert,
   Sum(CASE
         WHEN r.action = 'update' THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END) AS cnt_update,
   Sum(CASE
         WHEN r.action = 'verify' THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END) AS cnt_verify
```

FROM   auto_reminders_members r
WHERE  r.reminder_id = 1
       AND r.date_last_reminder BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '03/28/2013', 101) AND
                                            CONVERT(DATETIME,
                                            '03/28/2013' + ' 23:59:59.997 ', 101
                                            )

Comment: Yes, this is what many have posted as the correct solution.  You should probably select one of them as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select convert(nvarchar(10),warnt.created_dt,120) 'Date',loc.loc_name 'Location',--   
loctype.LocationTypeDesc,
 (select SUM(stk.sel_price) from tbl_mst_stock as stk 
inner join tbl_gen_warranty as wrn on stk.Stock_ID=wrn.Stock_Id
inner join tbl_mst_model as mdl on mdl.Model_ID=wrn.model_id
where wrn.mobile_type like 'SL')'Selleing Price',
(Select COUNT(stk.stk_code) from tbl_mst_stock as stk 
inner join tbl_gen_warranty as warn on stk.Stock_ID=warn.Stock_Id
inner join tbl_mst_model mdl on mdl.Model_ID=warn.model_id
    where warn.mobile_type like 'SL') 'Stock count'
From tbl_mst_location as loc 
inner join tbl_mst_location_types loctype on loc.LocationTypeID=loctype.LocationTypeID
inner join tbl_gen_warranty as warnt on loc.Location_ID=warnt.Location_id
Where  loctype.LocationTypeID=1 and loctype.group_id=1 
and (CONVERT(nvarchar(10),warnt.created_dt,120) 
Between CONVERT(nvarchar(10),'2013-01-01',120) and convert(nvarchar(10),'2013-07-09'))
Group by loc.loc_name,loctype.LocationTypeDesc,warnt.created_dt,loctype.LocationTypeID
```