# SQL - Convert values, count number of instances across multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, unpivot

I'm very new to SQL, and I'm not sure how to accomplish the following task: I have a set of data in a table, and I need to convert the data into one of two values, then adding up the totals per row in a pair of summary columns.  See below:

tbl1:

```
row    P1    P2    P3
---    ---   ---   ---
1      a     b     c
2      a     a     a
3      b     c     b
4      a     b     b
5      NULL  NULL  NULL
```

with a conversion table as:

```
PNum    PType
----    -----
a       car
b       truck
c       car
```

The desired end result:

```
row    P1    P2    P3    numCars    numTrucks
---    ---   ---   ---   -------    ---------
1      a     b     c     2          1
2      a     a     a     3          0
3      b     c     b     1          2
4      a     b     b     1          2
5      NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL       NULL
```

Code to get the test tables:

```
DECLARE @tbl1 TABLE(P1 VARCHAR,P2 VARCHAR,P3 VARCHAR)

INSERT INTO @tbl1
SELECT 'a','b','c' UNION ALL
SELECT 'a','a','a' UNION ALL
SELECT 'b','c','b' UNION ALL
SELECT 'a','b','b'


DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE(PNum VARCHAR,PType NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @tbl2
SELECT 'a','car' UNION ALL
SELECT 'b','truck' UNION ALL
SELECT 'c','car'
```

I've been looking into PIVOT but I'm having a hard time seeing how to implement it, (especially with the conversion piece).  I thought about trying to first insert a set of columns just to convert the values (e.g. "P1_converted"), then trying to summarize them but my actual table has 10 of these type columns and I didn't want to add an additionial 10 columns to the table if there is a simpler way.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Can you normalize your table?

Comment: If you don't understand @PolishPrince's comment, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: Also [please stop declaring columns, variables, params etc. as `VARCHAR` without length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx). You're lucky in this case that you only want single-character values in `P1,P2,P3`. Try inserting `'xy'` into one of them.

Comment: @Polish Prince, Dan Bracuk: I'll check into "normalizing" my table - I have no idea what that means.  Thanks for the lead.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: Duly noted.

Comment: Thanks for the sample data too, that is perfect, except the `@tbl1` declaration/population is missing the `[row]` column (and the 5th, empty row).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following which will *unpivot* the data to get the total count for the cars and trucks.

You can use the `UNPIVOT` function but since you are using SQL Server 2008, you can use `CROSS APPLY` and `VALUES` to convert your `P1`, `P2`, and `P3` from columns into rows. The code to convert the data is:

```
select *
from tbl1 
cross apply 
(
  values ('p1', p1), ('p2', p2), ('p3', p3)
) c(col, value)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f2f8/18). This converts the data to the format:

```
| P1 | P2 | P3 | COL | VALUE |
------------------------------
|  a |  b |  c |  p1 |     a |
|  a |  b |  c |  p2 |     b |
|  a |  b |  c |  p3 |     c |
|  a |  a |  a |  p1 |     a |
```

Once the data is in the rows, then you can easily join to the conversion table to get the count for each row:

```
select rn, p1, p2, p3,
  sum(case when t.ptype = 'car' then 1 else 0 end) numCars,
  sum(case when t.ptype = 'truck' then 1 else 0 end) numTrucks
from
(
  select p1, p2, p3,
    row_number() over(order by p1, p2, p3) rn
  from tbl1
) d
cross apply (values ('p1', p1), ('p2', p2), ('p3', p3)) c(col, value)
inner join tbl2 t
  on c.value = t.pnum
group by rn, p1, p2, p3
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f2f8/16). This gives the result:

```
| RN | P1 | P2 | P3 | NUMCARS | NUMTRUCKS |
-------------------------------------------
|  1 |  a |  a |  a |       3 |         0 |
|  2 |  a |  b |  b |       1 |         2 |
|  3 |  a |  b |  c |       2 |         1 |
|  4 |  b |  c |  b |       1 |         2 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach using `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT d.[row], d.P1, d.P2, d.P3, t.PType,
    [tc] = CASE WHEN t.PNum = d.P1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN t.PNum = d.P2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         + CASE WHEN t.PNum = d.P3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  FROM @tbl1 d CROSS JOIN @tbl2 t
) AS x
PIVOT (SUM([tc]) FOR PType IN ([car],[truck])) AS p;
```

Comment: [Did you see my answer yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15689664/61305)? :-)